# Subspace of $\alpha$ Holder continuous functions is Closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Lambda_{\alpha}([0,1])$ be the space of $\alpha$ Holder continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the norm:
$$\|f\|_{\Lambda_{\alpha}} = |f(0)| + \sup_{x,y \in [0,1], x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$$
and consider the subspace $\lambda_{\alpha}$ given by 
$$\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } x \rightarrow y \quad \forall \,  y\in[0,1]$$

I'm having trouble showing that for $\alpha < 1$ this is an infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\Lambda_{\alpha}([0,1])$. I showed it was a subspace (as a vector space). Is there some theorem I should be using here? I started with a cauchy sequence in $\lambda_{\alpha}$ but I'm having trouble saying anything about its limit -- other than it lives in $\Lambda_{\alpha}$.

---

EDIT: Does this work?

Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\lambda_{\alpha}$.
\begin{align}
        \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} & = \frac{|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}(x)-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_{n}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \\
  & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } x \rightarrow y
\end{align}

Comment: I suspect that $\lambda_\alpha$ equals the intersection $\bigcap_{\beta>\alpha}\Lambda_\beta$.

Comment: ah that's interesting I hadn't considered this

Comment: Yeah, that looks nice but beware. I am not that sure. Actually, now that I think a bit more about this, I think that it does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your edit, you can insert a zero:
\begin{align}
        \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} & 
\le  \frac{|f(x)-f_{n}(x)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}+\frac{|f_n(x)-f_{n}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} +\frac{|f_n(y)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} 
\end{align}
Choose $\epsilon>0$. Then the first and last term are less than $\epsilon/3$ for all $n$ large enough. Fix such an $n$. Then the second term is less than $\epsilon/3$ for $|x-y|$ small enough. This shows that 
$$ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\le 
\epsilon
$$
for all $y$ close to $x$. This is the claim.

Comment: The last term should be $f(y)$

Comment: @badatmath thanks, corrected